# Add new partition to already partitioned hive table

Tags: hive, partitioning, hive-partitions, hiveddl

I have a partitioned table `Student` which already has one partition column `dept`. I need to add new partition column `gender`

Will it be possible to add this new partition column in already partitioned hive table.

The table data does not have `gender` column. It is a new constant column to be added  in hive table.

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question (most probably you can't) but the thing I'm wondering about, does the table data already have the gender inside? If it doesn't, it is better to re-create the table with gender partition

Answer (score 1):

Partitions are hierarchical folders like `table_location/dept=Accounting/gender=male/` 
Folder structure should exist. You can easily add non-partition column as the last one and it will return NULLs if the data does not contain that column, but to add a partition column the easiest way is to create new table partitioned as you want, insert overwrite that table from the old one (selecting partitions columns as the last ones), drop old table, rename new one.

See this answer about dynamic partitions load: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48901871/2700344